# How to create redefinable type aliases that do not revert when scope is closed in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, types

I am trying to implement the class with about a functionality of std::any. More than that, I have decided I want to get rid of std::any_cast analogue if possible, so I can simply access the value stored in an instance of a class without explicitly stating its type while performing the access.

I tried to use `typedef` keyword as it allows for type alias redefinition, however, as the constructor or `operator=` scope closes, the type is reverted back to `void *`.

Do you have any ideas on how it would be possible to implement something like this?

What I have up to moment is something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
class any
{
public:
    any(){}
    template<typename T>
    any(const T&& other) : _ptr(new T(std::forward<const T>(other))), t(1)
    {
        typedef T _type;
        bool b = *(_type*)_ptr == other;
        _type tmp = *(_type*)_ptr;
    }
    template<typename T>
    void operator=(const T&& other)
    {
        typedef T _type;
        if(_ptr) delete _ptr;
        _ptr = new T(std::forward<const T>(other));
    }
    bool operator==(const any&& rval) const
    {
        try {
            return *(_type*)_ptr == *(_type*)rval._ptr ? true : false;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    bool operator==(const any& lval) const
    {
        try {
            return *(_type*)_ptr == *(_type*)lval._ptr ? true : false;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, any& val);
    auto val()
    {
        auto a = *(_type*)_ptr;
        return a;
    }
    operator bool()
    {
        return _ptr ? true : false;
    }
    ~any()
    {
        delete _ptr;
    }
    typedef void* _type;
private:
    void * _ptr;
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, any& val)
{
    os << val.val();
    return os;
}
```

Well, I can simply define any_cast function for the class, however, this is not what I am after in my research purposes.

Any advise will be appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to use a `typedef` as if it was a variable. That's not how it works. If you want to store type information you will need to use something like [std::type_intex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) and use runtime checks with `if` or `switch` or similar. This approach does not seem to make much sense to me as normally when you use a type-erased variable you need to know what type it is to actually use it. Have a look at the visitor pattern for more flexible ways of using your `any`s.

Comment: @super Thank you for your comment. Yeah, ```std::type_index``` does not seem to be a very flexible approach and knowing the type of the expression you wish to have is reasonable, though this is what I have tried to implement out of interest and not for a particular problem.

Thanks also for the reference to design patterns, I don't especially like them, however, if I come across an interesting one, they are interesting to look into.